# The Podfile contains framework or static library targets, for which the Podfile does not contain host targets

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I inherited an iOS project recently which has frameworks and uses CocoaPods. I'm trying to replicate this setup so I have a better understanding.

It has two frameworks (as Xcode projects) named `RaterCommon` and `RaterAPIKit`.

Here's the minimized version of its `Podfile` (I removed unnecessary parts).

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

workspace 'Rater'

target :Rater do
    # various pods
end

target :RaterCommon do
    project 'Libraries/RaterCommon/RaterCommon.xcodeproj'
end

target :RaterAPIKit do
    project 'Libraries/RaterAPIKit/RaterAPIKit.xcodeproj'
end
```

Upon running `pod install`, I get this warning.

> The Podfile contains framework or static library targets (RaterCommon,
>   RaterAPIKit), for which the Podfile does not contain host targets
>   (targets which embed the framework).

And I can't import these frameworks inside my main project's source either. Even after adding them in Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries in Xcode. It says No Such Module.

Comment: What all the targets do you have in your main app?

Answer (score 1):

Check that targets are really on that path

```
'Libraries/RaterCommon/RaterCommon.xcodeproj'
'Libraries/RaterAPIKit/RaterAPIKit.xcodeproj'
```

And afterwards do :

```
pod deintegrate && pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your framework path `Libraries/RaterAPIKit/RaterAPIKit.xcodeproj` in Framework Search Paths for every target or configuration that you have.
Framework Search Paths can be found inside Build Settings when showing all options.

Answer (score 0):

Add these pods to target where you are using these frameworks.

For eg-> There is a sample app which uses these RaterCommon and RaterAPIKit frameworks, so whatever pods you add in these targets should be added in Sample app too